# PM2 - Not Detecting Crash and Restarting

Tags: node.js, backend, vps, pm2

I thought with PM2, it would restart itself after an error causes it to stop working?  In my case, it'll be functioning fine, then all the sudden it's not working.  I have to manually stop and restart to get it working again.  How do I make this happen automatically?

As a side not, the status still says "Online" even when it stops working.

I haven't tracked down the error causing the issue yet, but would like to at least have it restarting itself as necessary in the meantime.  Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure about PM2 that wether it can track down crashed, but I had use monit to achive such requirement. You can take a look at it  https://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: That looks like it may do what I'm looking for.  Also appears it may be above my head.  I'll have to spend hours figuring that one out now.